# push post method data in jsonobject format using curl in php

Tags: json, curl

Below is the post data I have to push through curl API in PHP. I am getting `data not found error`, but succes in pushing same post data using postman API. 
POST DATA

```
{
    "PersonalDetails": {
        "SALUTATION": {
            "name": "Mr."
        },
        "FIRST_NAME": "Surendra",
        "MIDDLE_NAME": "A",
        "LAST_NAME": "Waso",
        "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "1988-10-20T18:30:00.000Z",
        "AGE": 28,
        "GENDER": {
            "type": "Male"
        },
        "MARITAL_STATUS": {
            "status": "Married"
        },
        "CHILD_COUNT": 1,
        "CHILD_LIST": [{
            "CHILD_NAME": "Ashwin",
            "CHILD_AGE": "1",
            "CHILD_GENDER": "Male"
        }]
    },
    "ProfessionalDetails": {
        "EDUCATION": {
            "education": "Graduate"
        },
        "PROFESSION_TYPE": {
            "professiontype": "Professional"
        },
        "INCOME_GROUP": {
            "incomegroup": "3.5 Lacs to 4.99 Lacs"
        },
        "INCOME": "375666"
    },
    "ContactDetails": {
        "ADDRESS_1": "HHU",
        "ADDRESS_2": "",
        "ADDRESS_3": "",
        "STATE": {
            "STATENAME": "MAHARASHTRA",
            "STATECODE": "18"
        },
        "CITY": {
            "CITY": "Akola"
        },
        "PINCODE": "444101",
        "PRIMARY_MOBILE": "8767856756",
        "SECONDARY_MOBILE": "",
        "PRIMARY_TELEPHONE": "",
        "EMAIL_ID": ""
    },
    "ExistingInsuDetails": {
        "HAS_HEALTH_INSURANCE": "N",
        "TOTAL_HEALTH_COVER": "0",
        "ANNUAL_PREMIUM_FOR_HEALTH_INSURANCE": "0",
        "HAS_TERM_INSURANCE": "Y",
        "TOTAL_LIFE_COVER": "0",
        "ANNUAL_PREMIUM_FOR_LIFE_INSURANCE": "0",
        "HAS_VEHICLE_INSURANCE": "Y",
        "VEHICLE_LIST": [{
            "VEHICLE_MAKER": "Honda",
            "VEHICLE_TYPE": "Car",
            "VEHICLE_MODEL": "Mobilio"
        }, {
            "VEHICLE_MAKER": "Datsun",
            "VEHICLE_TYPE": "Car",
            "VEHICLE_MODEL": "Go"
        }, {
            "VEHICLE_MAKER": "Datsun",
            "VEHICLE_TYPE": "Car",
            "VEHICLE_MODEL": "Go Plus"
        }],
        "HAS_INVESTED_MUTUAL_FUND": "N",
        "MUTUAL_FUND_VALUE": "0"
    },
    "ProductDetails": {
        "CATEGORY": {
            "categorycode": "C002"
        },
        "TYPE": {
            "producttype": "Non Par"
        },
        "SOLUTION": {
            "productname": "Income Replacement"
        },
        "PRODUCT_CODE": "",
        "EXPECTED_PREMIUM": "2,000",
        "EXPECTED_CLOSURE_DATE": "2017-10-08T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "LeadDetails": {
        "LEAD_SOURCE": {
            "campsource": "A002"
        },
        "CAMPAIGN_CODE": {
            "campname": "Compare and Cover",
            "campcode": "AP002"
        },
        "LEAD_CODE": "4543",
        "LEAD_STATUS": {
            "leadstatus": "Contact"
        },
        "LEAD_DISPOSITION": {
            "leadstatus": "Contact",
            "leaddisposition": "Call Back",
            "leadsubdisposition": "Asked to call back later"
        },
        "LEAD_SUB_DISPOSITION": {
            "leadstatus": "Contact",
            "leaddisposition": "Call Back",
            "leadsubdisposition": "Asked to call back later"
        },
        "SOURCE_REMARKS": "",
        "USER_REMARKS": "",
        "APPOINTMENT_TIME": {
            "hour": 11,
            "minute": 30,
            "meridian": "AM"
        },
        "ALLOCATED_TO": "N80012",
        "ALLOCATED_AT": "2017-09-10T18:30:00.000Z",
        "APPOINTMENT_DATE": "2017-09-13T18:30:00.000Z",
        "CREATED_AT_CC": "2017-09-13T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://your_url' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"your": "JSON"}'
```

please replace `your_url` with your real URL & `{"your": "JSON"}` with your big JSON data.